# How to get the port numbers of running Linux network services in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, network-programming, embedded-linux

My program needs to connect to a service via network socket. The client is on the same Linux machine as the server. Although the server has a known default port, it might be configured to run on a different port, which would needlessly break my client. Can I get a list of service names (or their executable path names) that are listening on network ports and on which ports they are bound to?

I have standard C and C++ libraries available, but not much more than that.

Comment: See [the `netstat` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/netstat.8.html) (and its source).

Comment: You could just use a [unix domain socket](https://troydhanson.github.io/network/Unix_domain_sockets.html) with a fixed path name instead of a TCP socket. You could still make the port (TCP) or path (unix socket) configurable (on both ends) to allow running multiple independent servers and clients simultaneously.

Comment: How do you configure the server's port number? If the port number is defined in `/etc/services` or similar you could use `getservbyname`. Or maybe you can read a configuration file of the server.

Comment: @Erlkoenig Unix domain sockets might me the way to go.
@Bodo, alas on my system the `getservbyname` is not available.

Comment: What if someone configured the server to have a different service name or executable path name?

Comment: You might want to consider using a multicast announce/discover protocol such as [avahi](https://www.avahi.org/).